# REST Uploading a Shapefile

Tags: rest, uploading, shapefile

I'm trying to upload a shape file with REST API.
Here is the error I get :
No such datastore: ws1,nete

I've installed version 1.7.5 together with the restconfig-1.7.5.jar plugin.

Here is what I do:
1) Create workspace ws1

curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d 'ws1'localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces

2) Check workspace

curl -XGET -H 'Accept: text/xml' localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/ws1

reply is ok

3) Upload shapefile

curl -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H 'Content-type: application/zip' --data-binary @roads.zip localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/ws1/datastores/roads/file.shp

Reply:

Warning: Couldn't read data from file "roads.zip", this makes an empty POST.
Error occured unzipping file:error in opening zip

need help please!!!

Answer (score 3):

I asked myself the same problem today, and solved it finally. I am running Geoserver 2.0.2 with REST extension.

The following curl command is working:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H 'Content-type: application/zip' --data-binary @/home/shape.zip http://localhost:8085/geoserver/rest/workspaces/ws/datastores/test1/file.shp
```

The "file" in front of ".shp" is arbitrary, use what you like.

"test1" is the name of the new datastore.

"/home/shape.zip" is path to a zipped Shapefile. Note: A Shapefile consists of multiple files! See wIkipedia for an introduction. A zipped Shapefie for Geoserver should at least contain .shp, .dbf, .shx, .prj.

If you are developing in Java, you might want to use a Java client to configure Geoserver via REST. [GSRCJ](http://code.google.com/p/gsrcj) is a very small (2 classes, zero dependencies) client written in Java 1.5+. It is not a complete implementation, but has working code of how to upload a Shapefile to Geoserver and more. See the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/gsrcj/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/geopublishing/RestUtil.java).

Comment: do we need shp file to be zipped? Can't we directly upload the shapefile as it is?

Comment: Well, a Shapfile consists of many single files, so a ZIP is usefull (and yes, needed) to put all the files together. See Wikipedia for a description of the many different files that are part of a "Shapefile" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Comment: thanks for the info @alfonx but I wanted to use this `curl` method to upload the shp directly without zipping it, http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-examples/rest-config-examples-curl.html#adding-an-existing-shapefile. Is that possible? I am trying it but it keeps giving me this error, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40601/why-is-the-curl-syntax-unable-to-create-datastore

Comment: You linked docs state for uploading a ZIP: "The following uploads the zipped shapefile roads.zip and creates a new datastore named roads".
For uploading only a .shp file it says: "This example shows how to add a shapefile that already exists on the server."
I guess that could mean, that if you only send a .shp file, a datastore can't be automagically created, since more info like the PRJ is needed. You could try to search on https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/geoserver-users

Comment: thanks for the reply @alfonx. I have around 88k shp files and to use this technique of adding shapefiles I will have to zip them all individually. Is that the only solution?